# How to activate the elements if different space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This if the same column on the elements that we click

```
<li class="root-level">
    <a href="#" class="levelentry">
        MAN
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="root-level">
    <a href="#" class="levelentry">
        WOMAN
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>

$(document).on('click', '.levelentry', function() {
    $('.level', this).addClass('active');
});
```

But how if like this. Because the `level` is not within `levelentry`. But still one room at a `root-level`

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="root-level">
        <a href="#" class="levelentry">MAN</a>
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="root-level">
        <a href="#" class="levelentry">WOMAN</a>
        <span class="dont"></span>
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="root-level"> ............ (etc)
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to use element `$(this)`? Is there any way other than using `$(this).next()`?

If i using

```
$(document).on('click', '.levelentry', function() {
    $('.level').addClass('active');
});
```

So, all `level` to be active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target `root-level` element then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to `level` element

```
$(document).on('click', '.levelentry', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.root-level').find('.level').addClass('active');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.levelentry', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.root-level').find('.level').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{background-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="root-level">
        <a href="#" class="levelentry">MAN</a>
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="root-level">
        <a href="#" class="levelentry">WOMAN</a>
        <span class="dont"></span>
        <div class="level">
            <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="root-level"> ............ (etc)
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()` on `$(this)`. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1650/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.levelentry', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.level').addClass('active');
});
```

If you want to select only first `.level` you can add `:first` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1651/) to `siblings('.level:first')`